# Js Shopping Cart; localStorage sets my cart to null

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

I'm trying to create a basic cart for a practice and I've ran into this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of null.

The error itself is clear, i just don't know how to go about it logically to fix it.

It occurs within my addItem() function which looks like this:

```js
    //adds items to the cart
    function addItem(name, price, quantity) {
        /*checks to see if the item with the identical name exists in the cart
        if so, it will only increment the quantity of the said item (no redundancies)*/
        for (var i in cartShop) {
            if(cartShop[i].name === name) {
                cartShop[i].quantity += quantity;
                saveLocalCart();
                return;
            };
        };
       var item = new Item(name, price, quantity);
        cartShop.push(item);
        saveLocalCart();
    };
```

It specifically occurs on the part where I say cartShop.push(item);

Then further down in the code, I call my loadLocalCart() function:

```js
    //a function for retrieving the cart state to the user
    function loadLocalCart() {
        //we use json.parse to return the stringified object back to a complex object.
        cartShop = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cartSession"));
    };
    
    loadLocalCart();
```

At this point it works alright ONLY if I have at least a single item object in the cartShop array, but as you can see, this very function pretty much sets the whole cart to pretty much null if you just start the session.

This error is triggered when I try to implement this feature:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        //assigning a click event to DOM object
    $(".add-to-cart").click(function(event){
        //prevents the page from being refreshed
        event.preventDefault();
        //sets the name variable to a clicked data-name
        var name = $(this).attr("data-name");
        //sets the price to the number version of data-price attribute
        var price = Number($(this).attr("data-price"));
        
        addItem(name, price, 1);
        displayCart();
    });
```

I'd appreciate your guys' input on how to approach this. If you guys are interested, i'm following the [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JPWKyv0m7i4&index=17&list=PLoN_ejT35AEhzNoPStBzAkpqAu3YQwPj7) video guide play list.

Comment: is cartShop global?

Comment: Could you create a deme on jsbin, jsfiddle, codepen?

Comment: The cartShop is global.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make sure cartShop is not null when loading, if it is make it an empty array

```
function loadLocalCart() {
    //we use json.parse to return the stringified object back to a complex object.
    cartShop = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cartSession"));
    if(!cartShop) cartShop = [];
};
```

Also do not use `for...in` loops for arrays as it could potentially iterate over keys that are not elements of the array. You can instead either use [for...of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) or the normal for loop

```
for(let item of cartShop) {
    if(item.name === name) {
        item.quantity += quantity;
        saveLocalCart();
        return;
    };
}
```

Comment: Ah, I'm surprised I didn't think of this myself. Thank you!

Comment: "Key's that are not elements of the array," how could that be possible?

Comment: @Vocaloidas, Have a look at the MDN article for [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in#Array_iteration_and_for...in), it will explain

Answer (score 1):

You could try adding the following as the first line of the addItem method.

```
cartShop = cartShop || [];
```

This code declares "cartShop" equal to "cartShop" if cartShop is declared, else it will be equal to a new array.

You could also use this in the loadLocalCart method as:

```
cartShop = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cartSession")) || [];
```

But this issue may be caused by the scope of your variables, you may want to look into that.